# Data not fetching in AngularJS

Tags: ajax, angularjs

While I'm clicking on "Show All Products", only the table header is displayg, not the data. I'm not getting any error also while controller is trying to get the data using AJAX call.

This is my complete code.

```
<html ng-app="mainApp">
<head>
    <title>grocerywww.com Admin Page</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="http://grocerywww.com/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.min.js"></script>

   </head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12" style="background-color: #ABCDEF; box-shadow: inset 1px -1px 1px #444, inset -1px 1px 1px #444;">
                <h1>grocerywww.com Admin Page</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3" style="background-color: #ABCDEF; box-shadow: inset 1px -1px 1px #444, inset -1px 1px 1px #444;">
                <span class="fake-link-heading"><b> PRODUCTS </b></span><br>
                <span class="fake-link" id="fake-link-list-all-products"><a href="#showProducts">Show All Products</a></span><br>

            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-9">

                <h2>AngularJS Sample Application</h2>
               <div>

                  <div ng-view></div>
                  <script type="text/ng-template" id="addStudent.htm">
                     <h2> Add Student </h2>
                     {{message}}
                  </script>

                <script type="text/ng-template" id="showProducts.htm">

                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <caption>PRODUCT'S LIST</caption>
                        <thead><tr><th>#</th><th>Product Name</th><th>Category Name</th><th>Image</th></tr></thead>

                        <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="product in productlist|orderBy:product_id ">
                                <td>{{product.product_id}}</td>
                                <td>{{product.brand_name}}<a id=product_{{product.product_id}}  class='product' href='#'> {{product.product_name}} </a><br>
                                <a id=imagepath_{{product.product_id}} class='imagepath' href='#'>{{product.product_image_path}}</a>
                                <input id=input_{{product.product_id}} class='imagepath_editbox' type='text' value={{product.product_image_path}} size='40px;'></td>

                                <td>{{product.sub_category_name}}</td>
                                <td><img src=http://grocerywww.com{{product.product_image_path}}  'width='75' height='75'/></td>

                                <td>
                                    <input id={{product.product_id}}_0_photo type='file' name={{product.product_id}}_0_photo /><br>
                                    <button type='button' id={{product.product_id}}_0_{{product.product_image_path}} class='btn btn-primary btn-sm fileUpload'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-upload'></span> Start Upload</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                </script>


               </div>

   <script>
        var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", ['ngRoute']);

        mainApp.config(['$routeProvider',
         function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.
               when('/addStudent', {
                  templateUrl: 'addStudent.htm',
                  controller: 'AddStudentController'
               }).
               when('/showProducts', {
                  templateUrl: 'showProducts.htm',
                  controller: 'ProductsController'
               }).
               otherwise({
                  redirectTo: '/addStudent'
               });
        }]);

        mainApp.controller('AddStudentController', function($scope) {
            $scope.message = "This page will be used to display add student form";
        });

        mainApp.controller('ViewStudentsController', function($scope) {
            $scope.message = "This page will be used to display all the students";
        });
        mainApp.controller('productsController', function($scope,$http) {
            $http.get("http://admin.localhost/cgi-bin/product.pl")
                .success(function(response) 
                {
                    $scope.productlist = response.products;
                    alert ('here');
                })

                .error(function(data, status, headers, config) 
                {
                    alert ('productsController Error');
                });
        });

   </script>
            </div>

</body>
</html>
```

M I Missing any thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your spelling of ProductsController - it is lower-case in your definition, but when you use it ,it is upper-case (first character).  Controller names are case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `.success(function(response)...` It should be `.success(function(data, status, headers, config)`. Then use `$scope.productlist = data.products`.

Comment: Those are the optional parameters. Anyways i tried with changes suggested by you, still same behavior.